# (Canvas, next.js)) Using canvas to generate a photo of a certain color and sending it back *without downloading it*

Tags: javascript, typescript, canvas, next.js, vercel

Im finally trying out next.js and im moving all of my stuff over, including a colour feature i have.

What i'm trying to do is use canvas to generate an image of a certain colour based on whats in the URL. It worked fine on express but when I locally host my next.js app, it works fine. However when i host and test it on Vercel it comes up with a 500 error.

Heres the code i've currently got:

```js
export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  const { color } = req.query;
  const canvas = createCanvas(200, 200);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = `#${color}`;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  const png = canvas.toBuffer();

  res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "image/png",
    "Content-Length": png.length,
  });

  res.end(png);
}
```

This code worked fine on express.js (the one above is slightly modified) so I don't know if i have to change a setting or Vercel or if its not supported etc. Thanks!

Comment: Where is `createCanvas` comes from?

Comment: @Danila I've done `import { createCanvas } from "canvas"` above the file. I forgot to copy my imports.

Comment: You could try some solutions from this thread https://github.com/vercel/vercel/issues/3460

Comment: I tried some of the solutions in that thread but unfortunately nothing came of it. Thanks anyway!